# How to escape whitespace in a bash alias?

Tags: whitespace, alias, bash, escaping

Tried to set some aliases in my .bashrc file. This one...

```
export alias umusic="/Volumes/180 gram/Uncompressed/"
```

...gets the following error...

> -bash: cd: /Volumes/180: No such file or directory

...when I try "cd $umusic".

I've tried various methods of escaping that whitespace in the directory name, to no avail. (180\ gram, 180%20gram, single quotes, double quotes, no quotes.) I realize the easiest solution is to rename the directory to "180gram," but I'd like to know how to solve this particular problem.

I'm on a Mac, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your use of the `export` command is making `umusic` an *environment variable* and not an *alias*. The `export` command exports environment variables named on the rest of the command line, optionally with new values. So it's exporting an environment variable named `alias` (which probably isn't set) and one named `umusic`.

Given that you're expanding an environment variable, the shell does the following substitution:

```
cd $umusic
cd /Volumes/180 gram/Uncompressed/
```

which generates the error you get because the space isn't quoted. If instead you do:

```
cd "$umusic"
```

then the expansion is

```
cd "/Volumes/180 gram/Uncompressed/"
```

which is what you're expecting.

However, using an environment variable for this might be still a bit too much work, since you have to quote the expansion. Instead, try this alias:

```
alias umusic="cd '/Volumes/180 gram/Uncompressed'"
```

which you would run with just

```
$ umusic
$ pwd
/Volumes/180 gram/Uncompressed
```

Comment: Thank you, and a related question: I thought aliases were supposed to serve as abbreviated file paths. It's OK to include a command in an alias?

Comment: A shell alias is an abbreviated command; they have no particular connection to file paths (except that they can contain paths, as Greg's suggestion does).

Comment: Note that the alias technique `alias umusic="cd '/Volumes/180 gram/Uncompressed'"` disallows the tilde from being interpreted as home.  Instead of the tilde (`~/`), you have to use `/home/yourUsername/` and this technique works great.