# Export environmental variable which contains path with spaces

Tags: bash, environment-variables, alias

I was trying to export some useful paths in **.bash_aliases**.
I figured out independently solution which is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911080/how-to-escape-whitespace-in-a-bash-alias).

However this restrict me to switching between the directories. I would like to use that variable also in scripts or just other commands and I do not always want to check whether I have to use quotes around it.

**What I am trying to achieve:**
I have WSL2 installed. I wanted to export my path to OneDrive into a custom variable. Something like this:

```
export onedrivepath1=/mnt/c/Users/Myuser/OneDrive\ -\ some-domain.at/
```

I want then use this variable  but I do not want always to think about that I need to use "$onedrivepath1".

I want to be able use it like this:

```
cd $onedrivepath1
cp $onedrivepath1/dir1/test.txt /home/myuser/Documents/
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Quote the variable.

Comment: So is it just correct way to always use quotes on path variables?

Comment: It's best to use quotes on any variable unless you need it to be split into separate arguments

Comment: Try `foo='a * b'` then compare  `echo $foo` with `echo "$foo"`